# Expo iOS build : ERROR ITMS-90085 when submitting with Transporter app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, itmstransporter

i built an React Native app with expo which is now online in the Apple App Store. I've tweaked it a bit and came with a new version that i'm trying to upload with Transporter (just like i did the first time). But this time Transporter is giving me this error message :

> ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to
> detect any architectures in the bundle executable."

here is my app.js :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Appname",
    "slug": "appname",
    "version": "0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#0042DA"
    },
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.name.name",
      "buildNumber": "0.2.0",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to take pictures and document the work achieved by the technician."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.name.name",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "permissions":["CAMERA", "CAMERA_ROLL"]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I've already built it twice... Any idea how i can solve this?
Best

Comment: Do you remember what you changed? Are you using `expo publish` to build the app? Does it give any warnings/errors?

Comment: i changed a lot of this component-wise, and the version numbers in the json. My mate tried to upload it too through transporter and he succeeded. I guess it comes from the fact that i dont' have XCode installed on my computer. Such a shame Apple forces you to install it though it weights tens of Gb and is useless !

Comment: Well, maybe it's not so useless after all. But yeah it's certainly possible that Transporter expects Xcode to be installed. At a very minimum you probably need to have Xcode Command Line Tools installed which you can do with `xcode-select --install` but I've never tried it on a computer without Xcode so not sure what it will do.